# How can I color letters or background (conditional) in cell - openpyxl or R?

Tags: python, r, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I need conditionaly change color of partial text of a cell. Is it posible?

My input is many of this sequence alignments (it is in text format, but I rewrite it to xlsx). All in one column:

```
>>f_1;KTD382xx1 hypothetical protein Labs_1969 [unknown] {gene:Labs_1969}_start=1;end=86;length=86;source_length=86
MFGFFSNVARTVTVDTVRTVAGTAVGLAAYQAAGYVQKTVLLDQRSQELKLAKQNEEAKSEEDPNWNPNPFAVDLDVLPRPSSFRA
&~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 | -0.499E+01 >>XXXXXXXX domain WP_01737xxxx hypothetical protein [Rickettsia] :_: Length: 161
#1 RTVAGTAVGLAAYQAAGYVQKTVLLDQRSQELKLAKQNEEA-KSEEDPNWNPNPFAVDLDVLPRPSS
#2 RPIGSASVGLQGFIETQRILDTLTDGNKKLELVFADSDDSSSKFKSDLNEFFNKYQSLIKALQNPSS
#c +------+++-----------+--------++--+-------+---+-+---+--------+--+++

>>f_1;KTD36892.1 hypothetical protein Labs_2028 [unknown] {gene:Labs_2028}_start=1;end=98;length=98;source_length=98
MPKPETEFTHLSDDALSRIGFFLSDTDRGRLASVNRQSFAVLGFSGYVKRVFGIDLSTFPLQALFFDASMVSERPEQLQLLRVLSLQEDYWQYAIVSE
&~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
5 | -0.404E+01 >>_vfdb.0001233_ VFG041279 (af) Dot/Icm type IV secretion system effector [Dot/Icm] [Legionella 1] :_: Length: 529
#1 KPETEFTHLSDDALSRIGFFLSDTDRGRLASVNRQSFAVLGFSGYVKRVFGIDLSTFPLQALFFDASMVSERPEQLQLLRVLSLQEDYWQYAIV
#2 KPGNIIIDFSKSPPI-----AKVIDFGFVLRASEQDYRRCGTRAYRA-------------------------PESFNTQALYTAKADVWSTGRI
#c ++-------+--------------+-+-------+-----+---+---------------------------++------------+-+-----
```

I want to color lines with #1 #2 conditionally eg. if letter A or C -> red background, yellow text, if letter D or N -> blue background, white text

```
input_file = 'input.txt'
output_file = 'output.xlsx'
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.active  

with open(input_file, 'r') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        ws.append(row)

wb.save(output_file)

from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('output.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')

for cell in ws['A']:
    if type(cell.value) is str:

       cell.font = Font(name='Courier New')
#here I am


wb.save( 'test.xlsx' )
```

Is this possible in openpyxl? Please suggest me what will help. Alternatively I thinking of R language (I am pretty novice in R,by the way in openpyxl too).

Comment: if you want to use `r` make sure you use a solution using package `openxlsx` since that's the best IMO.

Comment: Relevant [Editing workbooks with rich text in openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28793251/7414759)

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964251/how-to-find-and-replace-part-of-a-cell-with-formatted-text (solution uses VBA)